# PHP Script that reads strings from file and displays random string on click

Tags: php, string, file, random

I have a text document with around 100 different words that I want to randomly be displayed when a user clicks a button to view how would I go about doing this and display the string from the text file?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

```
$words = file('file.txt');
shuffle($words);
echo $words[0];
```

Comment: Although `shuffle` looks simpler, `echo $words[rand(0, count($words) - 1)]` is faster.

Comment: @JosephSilber   Have you benchmarked it?  I'm pretty skeptical about that...but even so, shuffle would certainly win out if OP decides to extends this script, depending on where he wants to go with it, eg: if he decides to show the whole list in a random order.

Comment: Will this allow me to basically have a user click a button to generate a code. After the button is clicked, a random string from the text file that has a list of 100 different string will be picked and that one string will be displayed.